# Background process called from script, dies after it ends

Tags: shell, cygwin, background-process

Something weird is happening on Cygwin.
I run a script that put some processes into background. However as soon as the script ends, they all die.

Simple example, take this script:

```
tail -f logfile.log &
```

I can see that the tail works (it prints the last X lines) but the process is not in the background anymore as soon as the script ends.

On Linux it behave differently, any idea why ?

Comment: Tried to reproduce this on my cygwin installation, and I don't see what you report.  After the script exits, tail is still running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try `nohup *cmd* &` on linux. But you will need to account for the file descriptors that get passed to the child. So `nohup *cmd* </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &` but where will the `tail -f` output go? Does the window close when you exit the shell? Then you can't exit the shell if you want to see the output.

Comment: The cygwin window stays open, so I can view the log while it is being tailed. If I run the commands directly from the shell and not from a script in the shell, everything works. but when I put them in a script, then after it ran, it will exit.

Comment: There are two ways to execute the contents of a script. You can source the script or you can execute the script. When you source a script, it is processed by the current shell so commands behave the same as when you type them directly to the script. Use `. Scrpt` to do this. When you execute a script, the current shell starts a new shell to process the commands in the script. Use `bash Scpt` or `./Scpt` to do this. This subshell will reap its children when it exits, i.e. kills and waits for exit for any child it starts, unless the child process protects itself from being killed by its parent.

Comment: Doug, that solved the problem, thank you for the great explanation. I was using ./Scrpt instead of . Scrpt and that was the problem. +1 to you.